# I'm using the Dlookup function not working as it should be

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, dlookup

'I have a Table name PublicHolidays that contain fields name :

'PHA_ID        as key field
'PH_Holiday    as a foreign key
'PH_Date       as a short date

'On a form a date is requested as M_Date
'The After Update event of M_Date is as follows :

```
Dim StDt As Date
StDt = M_Date
Me.Requery            ' -> Display all Public Holidays in SubForm    

Dim M_Id As Variant

M_Id = DLookup("PH_Holiday", "PublicHolidays", "PH_Date = #" & StDt & "#")
```

' StDt will be used in a loop afterward and increment by 1 till a specified end date
' The M_Id variable remains NULL to any date selected as M_Date in the Dlookup Function
' The value of StDt has been assign to PH_Date but nothing assign to PH_Holiday when using a Break point in the VBA.

Comment: Try `"PH_Date = #" & Format(StDt, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#"`.

Comment: Thanks, now it works as it should. thanks again and best regards.